# PyAutoGUI to .exe file

Tags: python, cmd, executable, pyautogui

I'm using a tool to convert my python files to .exe files. You can find the tool in this video [py to .exe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZSZHmWSOeM) .

Now when I convert this code, everything is fine:

```
width = float(input("Enter the width: "))
height = float(input("Enter the height: "))
area = width * height
print("The area is", area, "square units.")
```

But whenever I add a line of code with the PyAutoGUI module in it the .exe file instantly closes and does nothing.

example:

```
width = float(input("Enter the width: "))

pyautogui.moveTo(492, 106, 0.2)

height = float(input("Enter the height: "))
area = width * height
print("The area is", area, "square units.")
```

How can I prevent the .exe file from closing and why the PyAutoGUI code isn't executed?

Comment: Try running the .py as a python script instead of as an exe and check for any error messages. You could also start the exe via the CMD and check there if any errors appear

Comment: @äymm When I run the script in Pycharm the script works perfect, and no errors occur. Also when I run the .exe file from the CMD a window opens and instantly closes, so just no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This installer is using **PYINSTALLER** to create EXE's. PYINSTALLER uses the default python virtual environment while creating .exe. So, if you are using a virtual env which is not the default one (conda env or other venv) then the .exe will fail to run. So, when the default env is ready to run the program which means if you install all the required packages in the default env and use pyinstaller then there will be no issues. Hope I figured out the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. I did a few things so I'm not entirely sure but I think installing PyAutoGUI in the CMD made it work.